# Objective C @autoreleasepool directive

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I am reading a book which says (if I am not getting it wrong) wrapping some code with `@autoreleasepool` statement enables the ARC. First of all is this the case ?

My second concern is when I am doing some iOS example programs, although I enable ARC when creating a new project, I never see this directive being used anywhere (in the automatically generated code). Does this mean that ARC is not being used ? Any ideas/pointers is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@autoreleasepool` doesn't "enable" ARC. It's just the ARC way to use autorelease pools.

Before ARC, you used the [`NSAutoreleasePool`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class to set up an autorelease pool like this:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
// Code benefitting from a local autorelease pool.
[pool release];
```

But you're not allowed to call `release` when using ARC, so instead a new way to use autorelease pools was introduced:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    // Code benefitting from a local autorelease pool.
}
```

`@autoreleasepool` blocks are more efficient than using an instance of `NSAutoreleasePool` directly; you can also use them even if you do not use ARC.

Answer (score 4):

First off, the book is wrong. @autoreleasepool is orthogonal to ARC. You can use autoreleasepools without ARC and you can use ARC without autoreleasepools (but you shouldn't).

Secondly, the main thread of a project created using any of Xcode's default projects will have the autoreleasepool pool created for you. Any thread you create will need to create its own autorelease pool.

Answer (score 2):

> wrapping some code with @autoreleasepool statement enables the ARC

No. ARC is enabled by a compiler flag. `@autoreleasepool` is just a keyword used to create autorelease pools even if you're using ARC (because normally you would create and destroy them using alloc-init and release, respectively, but you can't send explicit `release` messages under ARC - that's why this keyword had been introduced.)

And if you enable ARC in Xcode/with the compiler/etc, it's enabled. Certainly, there are better solutions than the "autorelease everything" principle and that may be the cause of you not encountering this keyword in example code.

Answer (score 2):

> My second concern is when I am doing some iOS example programs, although I enable ARC when creating a new project, I never see this directive being used anywhere (in the automatically generated code). Does this mean that ARC is not being used ? Any ideas/pointers is appreciated.

You application does use this. Check out the **main.m** file in your project. You will find it there.